# How to add field from other model in email template in odoo?

Tags: xml, templates, odoo, odoo-8, email-templates

I created an email template in odoo. Its model is `sale.order` and I am calling field from this model by using `${object.name}`. Now I want to add more fields in this template which are from other table `stock.picking`, but I am not getting that how I can call field from other table in email template.

I used for loop in template file but not succeeded.

**template.xml**

```html
<record id="order_alert_warehouse_email_template" model="email.template">
    <field name="name">TOV- Alert When Order Ship Out</field>
    <field name="email_from">processing@tovfurniture.com</field>
    <field name="subject">Tov Furniture Notification Mail ${object.name}- Order Shipped</field>
    <field name="email_to">leftwarehouse@tovfurniture.com</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
    <!--<field name="report_template" ref="sale.report_sale_order"/>
    <field name="report_name">
        ${(object.name or '').replace('/','_')}_${object.state == 'draft' and 'draft' or ''}
    </field>-->
    <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
    <field name="user_signature" eval="False"/>
    <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
    <p>${object.name} is shipped!</p>

    <p>Reference number is ${object.client_order_ref}</p>

    <p>Scheduled date is ${object.expected_date}</p>

    <p>Tracking number is
    % for stock in object.stock_ids:
          ${stock.carrier_tracking_ref}
    % endfor
    </p>

    <p>All the Best,</p>

    <p>Your friends at TOV</p>

    ]]></field>
</record>
```

Here tracking number field `carrier_tracking_ref` is from another table which is **stock.picking**.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is the rendered template just plain white?

Comment: no I was not getting any error, tracking field was not showing tracking number, but i resolve it by adding for loop correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer, i resolved it by myself, it was just for loop issue, by using for loop i called field from other object. Now its working, let me share my for loop code which i added in email template.

```html
<p>Tracking number is
     % for pickings in object.picking_ids:
          ${pickings.carrier_tracking_ref}
     % endfor
</p>
```